# C++ Combining overloading and overriding results in strange behaviour

Tags: c++, overloading, overriding

Consider the following code

```
class X{
public:
    virtual void foo(X x){  }
    virtual void foo(int index){ }

};

class Y : public X{
public:

    void foo(int index){ }
};


int main(){
    Y y;
    y.foo(X()); //Error, see below
}
```

Class `X` has overloaded the virtual `foo` method. One version takes an `X` and the other one takes an `int`. Now class `Y` inherits from `X` and overrides the method `foo(int)`. The method `foo(X)` is not to be overridden, it should stay the same.

However, when creating an object of type `Y` in the `main` method and calling `foo(X)`, the compiler complains the following:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
error: no matching function for call to ‘Y::foo(X)’
note: candidate is:
note: virtual void Y::foo(int)
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘X’ to ‘int’
```

Thus, the only candidate is the overridden `foo(int)` method. It seems that the other method has simply vanished. If I remove the overriding version, i.e. declare `Y` as `public Y : public X{};`, then everything works fine. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a derived class defines a member with *same* name as the one in the base class, the derived class name hides the base class name.

In your case, the function `Y::foo` *hides*  `X::foo`. You need to bring it into the scope of `Y` as:

```
class Y : public X{
public:

    using X::foo;  //it brings X::foo into the scope of Y

    void foo(int index){ }
};
```

Comment: why is this? It means that, by default, the derived class violates Liskov's principle which is a quite bad design decision for C++.

Comment: @gexicide: Actually it doesn't violate the LSP, since when you access the derived class *via a pointer or reference to the base class*, all of the base class's methods are still available as usual.

Comment: @gexicide: The reason for this language decision is that not hiding the base class function might lead to unexpected behaviour. Imagine that, instead of an `X`, the other base class overload took a `double`. A user of class `Y` might call `y.foo(2.5)`, expecting `Y::foo(int)` to be called; instead, `X::foo(double)` would be called; a function that user does not expect to exist.

Comment: A little clarification of terminology: a function **overrides** a **virtual** function in a base class when it has the same name and the argument list and the same return type (modulo covariant references and pointers). Name hiding is only about defining something in the derived class with the **same name** as something in the base class; it doesn't depend on overriding, nor is it limited to functions. `int foo;` in `Y` would also hide the `foo` members of `X`.

Comment: @Gorpik: Of course the user should expect that `X::foo(double)` exists. This is what the LSP is about.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: But still, if I got a reference to the derived class, the LSP dictates that it should be capable of everything that the base class is also capable of.

Comment: @gexicide: The user might not necessarily be aware of the interface of class `X`. The definitions of classes `X` and `Y` will probably be in different header files.

Comment: @gexicide: I admit I haven't read Liskov's paper(s), but I'm certain that what counts is whether an object of the derived class can be substituted for every object of the base class without breaking any contracts.  The whole point of the LSP is that derived classes that obey it can safely be used by code that *only knows about the base class* (i.e. code that doesn't contain any references having the static type of reference-to-your-derived-class).

Comment: @gexicide: Even if the LSP [or its common reinterpretation in the context of inheritance] were an unbreakable rule (which it isn't), or important enough to force obedience even at the cost of a "fragile base class" problem (which is debatable), it didn't become fashionable until many years after the C++ object model was invented. By that time, it was far too late to change a fundamental behaviour of the language.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: It's a shame that the LSP wasn't widely known until long after C++ came around, and certainly you can violate it for fun and profit if you like, but in the case of overloading that we're talking about here: C++ doesn't inherently violate the LSP.

Comment: But now suppose I have different overloads with different visibility (e.g., protected and public). By using `using X::foo` I pull all of them with public visibility into the scope of `Y`, which is not what I want. How can I preserve the visibility of the overloaded methods?

Comment: @gexicide: Indeed that is impossible TTBOMK.  One of many warts in C++ :-/  Still: I can't think of a case where it would be a good idea to assign different visibility to overloads of a given name -- can you?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Of course I can. Suppose a `getPayload` method that receives some payload object. One overloading takes a security wrapper object that is security checked and then unwrapped. The unwrapped object is then handed to the overloaded method. Since only code inside the class hierarchy should be able to access the `getPayload` method without performing a security check, this method would be `protected`. Of course, this can be solved by renaming one of the methods. However, each overloading related problem (not considering templates) can be solved that way.

Comment: @gexicide: In that case, I'd be thinking about the Single Responsibility Principle, and making two classes: a wrapper which performs the security check, with a private delegate to access the payload. That way, both behaviours can be tested separately, and there's no need for any inheritance relationships at all (except perhaps a purely abstract interface).

Comment: @gexicide: The only increase in expressive power that overloading affords is in enabling a single function template to operate on multiple different types.  If you want a function template to be able to call a function named `getPayload()` on any of several types, you almost certainly want all those overloads of `getPayload()` to have the same visibility.  Whenever you call an overloaded function from non-templated code, such as in your example, you already know the particular function you want to call, so in these cases it's just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

Overloading applies to names **defined in the same scope**. So the `foo` in class `Y` does not overload the `foo`s in class `X`, because they are defined in different scopes. This is known informally as "name hiding". To pull base class names into the derived class, add a using directive:

```
using X::foo;
```